# Excel List - Dynamic

Tags: excel

I have a list in Excel that allows me to drag-and-drop the following:

```
Y2014 Jan
Y2014 Feb
Y2014 Mar
Y2014 Apr
Y2014 May
Y2014 Jun
Y2014 Jul
Y2014 Aug
Y2014 Oct
Y2014 Nov
Y2014 Dec
```

I want the list to continue to Y2015 Jan and way beyond, but a list can only contain 255 characters. Is there a way to make this list continue? I want to be able to drag this list indefinitely, so that the year adjusts appropriately. Is this possible?

Comment: What problem you facing to do that?

Comment: Why does the character limit matter? Why are you trying to fit 255 characters in a cell?

Comment: I want the list to continue on to future years, but it loops in 2014 instead of continuing into 2015. That's why the character limit matters, otherwise I could just continue the list into future years manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to a custom list, then you may want to consider a different approach.

Instead of a list, use real dates. In the first cell enter Jan-1-2014, next cell Feb-1-2014. Enter the dates according to your regional settings, so Excel recognizes them as dates, not as text. Then format with custom format

`\Yyyyy mmm`

Now drag down as far as you want. Excel recognizes that you want to increment by one month and the formatting shows the desired characters.

[image]

Alternative: You can have the real date in a helper column and drag down as described above. Leave the standard date format. In the column that is used by the macro, you can put a formula like this (if your date helper column is column Z, data starts in row 2):

=TEXT(z2,"\Yyyyy mmm")

The result of this formula is text. Drag down as far as required.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I am using a database macro on some data that specifically searches for the dates the way I typed them - it cannot be dates that are formatted to look like it like it. It sounds ridiculous, and believe me it is very annoying but there is nothing I can do. I am not in charge of the database. Your solution was the first I tried, and unfortunately it doesn't work. The cell needs to contain Y2014 Jan in general formatting. :(

Comment: If you use a macro, why not let the macro add the text? Use the formula I gave above and let the macro paste the formatted value into the cell.

Comment: If the macro just does the searching, change he macro to search for the date instead of the text.

Comment: The macro is not controlled by me, it is controlled by people who manage the database and is password protected. I guess I will just create my own macro that converts dates to this format, and then converts them to a regular string. My question is if I could do this with a list instead.

Comment: I posted an alternative.